# Change input in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I have a ruby app that runs on heroku. I am trying to alter the input of one column in my database. I have looked around the net and stack and found that others have had luck using this line of code...

```
user.find(8338).update_attributes(:sport=>"men's swimming")
```

However when I try this I get an error stating...

```
irb(main):005:0> User.find(8338).update_attributes(:sport=>”men’s 
swimming”)
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting 
keyword_do or '{' or '('
:sport=>”men’s swimming”)
                          ^
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties- 
   5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties- 
   5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties- 
   5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties- 
   5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties- 
   5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I have tried many alterations of the above code and get the same error. Can anyone help with this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `”` (right double quotation mark) is not the same character as the regular double quote `"` and does not work as a string delimiter in Ruby. `User.find(8338).update_attributes(:sport=>"men’s 
swimming")` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User.find(8338).update_attributes(:sport=>”men’s 
>   swimming”)

Those double quotes look suspicious. You should be using the normal " and not whatever it is you typed in there.